# Why the Q1 and Q3 is different from what I think?

Tags: r, quantile, iqr

I have a very confusing question about quantile. I have a sample here and its Q1 and Q3 should be like this:
[image]
But when I summary the vector in R I got a different result:

```
summary(A)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>    1.00    2.75    4.50    4.50    6.25    8.00
```

I got different results of Q1 and Q3. OMG what happened? Thanks many in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to calculate quantiles. Read the documentation

```
?quantile
```

And you'll see how R does it by default and what the other... 8 or so options are.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! But how can I tell which one is the best? Or most of the time which one people are going to use? (I'm just a beginner of statistics).

Comment: "best" isn't well defined. It depends on your situation and your data.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much!